# Python function to count syllables in a word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this function to count the syllables in a word using Python to complete an exercise.

The exercise's text is:

> Return the number of syllables in the given word, according to this
>   rule: Each contiguous sequence of one or more vowels is a syllable,
>   with the following exception: a lone "e" at the end of a word is not
>   considered a syllable unless the word has no other syllables. You
>   should consider y a vowel.

I also disagree with the text because using the given instructions the syllable count for the word "example" are 2 and should be 3.

But, as discussed in the comments, the exercise text is the one that I implemented and would like to get suggestions and improvements for.

```
def count_syllables(word):
    word = word.lower()
    counter = 0
    is_previous_vowel = False
    for index, value in enumerate(word):
        if value in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"]:
            if index == len(word) - 1:
                if value == "e":
                    if counter == 0:
                        counter += 1
                else:
                    counter += 1
            else:
                if is_previous_vowel == True:
                    counter += 1
                    is_previous_vowel = False
                    break
            is_previous_vowel = True
        else:
            if is_previous_vowel == True:
                counter += 1
            is_previous_vowel = False
    print ("In \"{}\" I count {} syllables".format(word, counter))

count_syllables("coding")
```

Comment: You could possibly try bit masking. Using `ord` function you can convert any character to its 8 bit integer representation. Then you could write instead of *`for`* an *`while loop`* till end character is found (`0x00`), where your counter would then be `counter += 1 if (ord(word[i]) & 97 == 97 else 0`. You can see what integer representations of your vowel letters are by going into console and just `list(map(ord, 'aeiouy'))`. With while loop you can save in speed by not assigning length of string. GKeyWords: Bitwise operators.

Comment: I also disagree with the text, although for the different reasons. There are plenty of words in which successive vowels form distinct syllables; there are plenty of (mostly borrowed) words in which final `e` forms a syllable; treatment of `y` is too simplistic (say, `beyond`). However I am curious how did you come up with 4 syllables in `example`. Nevertheless, the problem statement is what has to be implemented.

Comment: @vnp Horrible typo! 3 and not 4 syllables for example, obviously.
I also see that the exercise track was written in this way for simplification.
Indeed the Code Review should be mainly code related so I will consider as good answer the one that improves my code and just follow the given exercise track.
Obviously if a great coder comes with a complete solution working for real English that would simply be awesome for me and other people on the planet, I guess :)

Comment: So you just want someone to do the example instead of you ? Smart. 
You are missing the main question. The code works so you have no major bugs. There is of course optimisation and readability/speed improvement, but since you've changed your question a bunch of times ( i don't mind that ), it is unclear what are you expecting to get from Review.

Comment: @Danilo
What do you mean by "instead of me"?
I already did a complete and working version of the code, as you can read in the post.
All I am looking for is improvements / more efficient / more elegant version of it.
This is the main idea behind this site, no?
On the other side, while discussing with vpn, seemed obvious that also the text of the exercise would not obtain 100% correctness in English.
I just think it would be nice bonus if we can get a 100% working version in English but it is not the aim of this question, only focused on given code improvements.

Comment: @Pitto this " I will consider as good answer the one that improves my code and just follow the given exercise track." sentence gives off a feeling of delegating work. I might be wrong. So what is the aim of the question ? Improve code, make it efficient and elegant? So in short readable , faster and simple code ? If that is so perhaps you could add that to the question so you don't get a bunch of iterations of your own code.

Comment: @Danilo Forgive me if my clarity is not top notch but English is not my main language. The work I had to do is already done so what am I delegating? This website is code review and people post their code to... Get reviews. I tried to explain better what I will consider a good result so if someone decides to give it a try already knows better what I'd be looking for and what could probably be useful for next readers. Here's how to ask a good question: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/checklist-for-how-to-write-a-good-code-review-question  I don't think mine is terrible.

Comment: If I came here to ask this question is because I want to learn more and better Python and because I hope to contribute to write a good count syllable function that might be useful for other in future, that's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a good practice to promote code reuse, the function should `return` a numeric result.  The `print()` should be done by the caller.

Constantly referring to `is_previous_vowel` is tedious. There are a couple of solutions you could use involving [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). In particular, `groupby()` and `zip_longest()` could be useful.

Ultimately, the simplest solution is to use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to declare what you are looking for: one or more consecutive vowels (`'[aeiouy]+'`), but not an `e` at the end (`'(?!e$)`).

```
import re

def count_syllables(word):
    return len(
        re.findall('(?!e$)[aeiouy]+', word, re.I) +
        re.findall('^[^aeiouy]*e$', word, re.I)
    )
```

Comment: This is a masterpiece